# Compute an addrow function not working javascript php

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I could not solve the issue whenever I execute my `addrow()` function, the computation sudden stop working.Once I `addrow()`, the computation not working.  Here is my code:

```js
$('#addrow').click(function() {
  var length = $('.sl').length;
  var i = parseInt(length) + parseInt(1);
  var newrow = $('#next').append('<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-1"><label for="Age">Sl No:</label><input type="text" class="form-control sl" name="slno[]" value="' + i + '" readonly=""></div><div class="col-sm-3"><label for="BL NO">BL NO:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="bl_no[]" id="bl_no' + i + '" placeholder="Enter BL NO"></div><div class="col-sm-3"><label for="container">CONTAINER:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="container[]" id="container' + i + '" placeholder="Enter container"></div> <div class="col-sm-7"><label for="delivery_address">DELIVERY ADDRESS:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="delivery_address[]" id="delivery_address' + i + '" placeholder="Enter Address"></div>  <div class="col-sm-7"><label for="item_description">ITEM DESCRIPTION:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="item_description' + i + '" name="item_description[]" placeholder="Enter item_description"></div><div class="col-sm-3"><label for="delivery_date">DELIVERY DATE:</label><input type="date" id="delivery_date' + i + '" name="delivery_date[]" class="form-control"/></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="shipping_line_cost">SHIPPING LINE COST:</label><input type="number" id="shipping_line_cost' + i + '" name="shipping_line_cost[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="sum()"/></div><div class="col-sm-3"><label for="base_tax_cost">BASE TAX COST:</label><input type="number" id="base_tax_cost' + i + '" name="base_tax_cost[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="sum()"/></div><div class="col-sm-3"><label for="additional_charges">ADDITIONAL CHARGES:</label><input type="number" id="additional_charges' + i + '" name="additional_charges[]" class="form-control"/></div><div class="col-sm-3"><label for="delivery_charge">DELIVERY CHARGE:</label><input type="number" id="delivery_charge' + i + '" name="delivery_charge[]" class="form-control"/></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="mano_charge">MANO CHARGE:</label><input type="number" id="mano_charge' + i + '" name="mano_charge[]" class="form-control"/></div> <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="collectible_amount">COLLECTIBLE AMOUNT:</label><input type="number" id="collectible_amount' + i + '" name="collectible_amount[]" class="form-control" readonly/></div>  <input type="button" class="btnRemove btn-danger" value="Remove"/></div><br>');

});
// Removing event here
$('body').on('click', '.btnRemove', function() {
  $(this).closest('div').remove()

});

function sum() {
  var shipping_line_cost = document.getElementById('shipping_line_cost').value;
  var base_tax_cost = document.getElementById('base_tax_cost').value;
  var result = parseInt(shipping_line_cost) + parseInt(base_tax_cost);
  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('collectible_amount').value = result;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <label for="shipping_line_cost">SHIPPING LINE COST:
  </label>
  <input type="number" id="shipping_line_cost" name="shipping_line_cost[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="sum()" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <label for="base_tax_cost">BASE TAX COST:
  </label>
  <input type="number" id="base_tax_cost" name="base_tax_cost[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="sum()" />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <label for="shipping_line_cost">COLLECTIBLE AMOUNT:
  </label>
  <input type="number" id="collectible_amount" name="collectible_amount[]" class="form-control" readonly/>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="next">
</div>
<br/>
<button type="button" name="addrow" id="addrow" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Add New Row
</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-left">Submit
</button>
```

Comment: How is this related to PHP? It seems like a frontend question. You should also edit the question go include some examples of what actually happens and what you expect to happen. What debugging have you done? Where does it fail? "Not working" doesn't really give us much to go on.

Comment: *"the computation not working..."* this is very vague. Please provide some details about the issue you're facing.

Comment: Clearly a jQuery and HTML issue, not php, so I amended the tags. As you're new, to improve your experience on Stackoverflow and avoid downvotes, requests for clarification etc, I suggest to read the [tour] and [ask] as the system suggested you to do before you posted anything (but which I can see from your empty profile you didn't), and also [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). You can [edit] your post to clarify the situation fully.

Comment: Are those JS snippets on different pages, since you're loading jQuery in both? _Very_ different versions at that. In the second snippet, you're not even using jQuery at all.

Comment: "Not working" isn't an error message or a useful problem statement. We can't fix "not working" in code, like a mechanic can't fix a car that is "not working" without any other information about the problem. How isn't it working? What [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) have you done? What exactly happens when you run this? What did you expect to happen instead? Please provide details of error messages, unexpected behaviour etc. See also [What do you mean "It doesn't work"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code is because you're dynamically creating multiple incremental `id` attributes on the elements you create in each row, yet your JS logic expects there to only ever be 1 of each id.

To fix the issue you need to loop through the new content which you dynamically create and sum up each value as you go.

There's also several other issues with your code which need to be addressed:

- You're using multiple versions of jQuery. Reference a single version and use that one only.
- Remove `id` attributes from dynamic content and replace them with `class` attributes. You can then use DOM traversal methods to relate the elements together when required.This makes the code more DRY and easier to maintain.
- Use a `<template />` element to store the dynamic HTML. You should avoid having HTML in your JS as much as possible, otherwise the JS becomes an unmaintainable mess.
- Wrap the `label` elements *around* the `input`. This way you don't need to use any `id` attributes.
- Use unobtrusive delegated event handlers on dynamic content. Do not use `onclick`, or any other `onX` event attribute in your HTML. They are no longer good practice.
- Use the `input` event instead of `keyup`, `keypress` etc. It also covers cases where the user pastes content using the mouse, and is generally better for accessibility.

With all those changes applied, your code should look and work something like this:

```js
const rowTemplateHtml = $('#row-template').html();
const $container = $('#next');
const setIndexValues = () => $container.find('.sl').val(i => i + 1);

$('#addrow').on('click', e => {
  $container.append(rowTemplateHtml);
  setIndexValues();
});

$container.on('input', '.sum', e => {
  const $row = $(e.target).closest('.row');
  var result = $row.find('.sum').get().reduce((acc, el) => acc + parseInt(el.value || 0, 10), 0);  
  $row.find('.collectible_amount').val(result);
});

$container.on('click', '.btnRemove', e => {
  $(e.target).closest('div').remove();
  setIndexValues(); 
});
```

```css
#next {
  margin: 20px;
} 
.row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label for="shipping_line_cost">SHIPPING LINE COST:</label>
        <input type="number" id="shipping_line_cost" name="shipping_line_cost[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="sum()" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label for="base_tax_cost">BASE TAX COST:</label>
        <input type="number" id="base_tax_cost" name="base_tax_cost[]" class="form-control" onkeyup="sum()" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label for="shipping_line_cost">COLLECTIBLE AMOUNT:</label>
        <input type="number" id="collectible_amount" name="collectible_amount[]" class="form-control" readonly/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="next"></div>
    <button type="button" name="addrow" id="addrow" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Add New Row</button>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-left">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<template id="row-template">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">  
      <label>
        Sl No:
        <input type="text" name="slno[]" class="form-control sl" readonly>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>
        BL NO:
        <input type="text" name="bl_no[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter BL NO">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>
        CONTAINER:
        <input type="text" name="container[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter container">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <label>
        DELIVERY ADDRESS:
        <input type="text" name="delivery_address[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Address">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <label>
        ITEM DESCRIPTION:
        <input type="text" name="item_description[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter item_description">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>
        DELIVERY DATE:
        <input type="date" name="delivery_date[]" class="form-control" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>
        SHIPPING LINE COST:
        <input type="number" name="shipping_line_cost[]" class="form-control sum" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>
        BASE TAX COST:
        <input type="number" name="base_tax_cost[]" class="form-control sum" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>
        ADDITIONAL CHARGES:
        <input type="number" name="additional_charges[]" class="form-control" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>
        DELIVERY CHARGE:
        <input type="number" name="delivery_charge[]" class="form-control" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>
        MANO CHARGE:
        <input type="number" name="mano_charge[]" class="form-control" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <label>
        COLLECTIBLE AMOUNT:
        <input type="number" name="collectible_amount[]" class="form-control collectible_amount" value="0" readonly/>
      </label>
    </div> 
    <button type="button" class="btnRemove btn-danger">Remove</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

As an aside, you seem to be working with monetary values, so the use of `parseInt()` may not be a good choice. I'd suggest `parseFloat()` instead.

Comment: I forgot to mention about on how could I save this into my database since the code was replaced?

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I'd suggest starting a new question about how you save the data, as it's a broad topic which depends on your server side platform.